# How can I use getResources inside of onBindViewHolder()?

Tags: android

I have this method, and I want to use getResources() inside it:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[i]);
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);


       viewHolder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.item_image, 200, 200));
    }
```

Comment: you must have a `Context` reference variable in your adapter so use `context.getResources()`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Resources res = viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources();
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works great until you rotate the device and the Fragment is no longer attached to a context, causing a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 6):

> i can't use getResources inside onBindViewHolder()?

yes, you can. Use

```
   viewHolder.itemView.getResources();
```

`getResources()` is part [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getResources()). No need to pass `Context` around

Answer (score 0):

pass the `Activity` Context `this` in your Adapter class:

```
 Context context ;
 public YourAdapter(Context context ,... )  //constructor
 {
    this.context = context ;
    //other code
 }
```

then u can use:

```
context.getResources() ;
```

Comment: how do u call onAttach() in adapter..?

Comment: no the comment was not meant for u...someone suggested to use onattach to get context !!

Comment: You shouldn't pass context to the adapter, because it can lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score -1):

get `Context` object by the `Adapter` constructor.

```
private Context context;

public YourAdapter(Context context){    //or you can make other method  to get/set Context obect
     this.context = context;
}
```

Then you can use `this.context.getResources()` to access `getResources()` method.

And initialize your adapter from Activity or Fragment, like -

```
YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```